# Get graphics object that is drawn by Graphics.DrawString(..) method?

Tags: c#, animation, intersection, drawstring

I am working on a project where I need my drawn animation with letter on the form - and check when falling letter reaches a certain position.

The thing is that I would like to use the method `IntersectsWith` but can not do that since the `DrawString()` method is not an object is just a void method.

What do you suggest how can I check whether text reaches certain position?

I want my letters which are drawn to the form to act like `Object`'s - so that I can do things with them afterwards.

Comment: So build objects representing the letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, that returns bounds of specified string on given system at runtime. So having that information in your hands you can also make your calculations.

In alternative you van use [Piccolo](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/jazz/) framework, that have much more then that, and also works pretty well.